# ASP.NET WEB-API after 10 POSTS Timeout

Tags: asp.net, api

I have a Problem with an ASP.NET WEB-API. The API is running on a Windows Server 2019.
After 10 Posts, I get a Timeout in my code from another Program.

Is it possible, that the Windows Server 2019 has a DDOS Protection witch allows only 10 requests?

Thanks for your help!
Lars

Comment: The Server is my own one. I've the full control over it.

Comment: Unless you added some sort of request rate limiting, there isn't anything that I know of that would cause it to time out after 10 posts. Have you checked the web server log to see if the request made it to the server? It it always exactly 10 requests? Does it start working again after some time, or do you have to restart the client or server?

Comment: Where can I find the web server log? Yes, exactly after 10 requests I get the Timeout. I have to restart the client, to get It work again.

Comment: 1) Presumably you are using IIS, so the default location for the log files is `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`. 2) If you have to restart the client to make it work, it seems likely that there is something on the client blocking the requests—what anti-virus software is installed?